# asp.net forms ScriptManager __doPostback

Tags: asp.net, postback, scriptmanager

Why does the ScriptManager ALWAYS insert the __doPostback method in javascript, even on an empty page where no controls can cause a postback?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is because by default ScriptManager assumes partial rendering. You can disable it like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I will disable partial rendering on pages not using an updatepanel.